# how to have different root for json render in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to merge three function in to function as below , i want to render json data but for different root

```
def user 
     user_data = User.all
      render json: user_data, root: users
end 

def contact 
     contact_data = Contact.all
      render json: contact_data, root: contact
end 

def ammo 
     ammo_data = Ammo.all
      render json: ammo_data, root: ammos
end
```

I want to merge the above functions to one

reason for merging is because previously we call  3 different api from frontend model hook , trying to optimise by reducing the effort in model hook by coming the tree function in to one ,so we will hit one api call

but having issue in figuring the root for render function ,

```
def comined_function 
contact_data = Contact.all
ammo_data = Ammo.all
user_data = User.all

 render json: {user: user_data, contact: contact_data, ammo: ammo_data} root: ?

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have nested hash like this

```
render json: { data: { user: user_data, contact: contact_data, ammo: ammo_data } }
```